# Forward selected class to use in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method

I'm having a bit of a brain fart. I hope someone can help me.

I have an app that communicates with different devices. Based on which device it's communicating with, I need to use different methods.

I have several different classes that do some parsing that I have made subclasses of a class called `Parse` (Don't confuse with the Parse cloud service), these only have Class methods. e.g. `Parse_Device1` `Parse_Device2`

I have a third class (lets call it `Selection`) that returns all sorts of different stuff depending on what device the app is communicating with.

How can I have this class return the needed `Parse` subclass and use what's returned?

I know I could easily `alloc` and `init` the needed class, store it or return it.
However as all the methods on the parse classes are just Class methods, there's no need to `init` at all.

I've tried like this, however I don't seem to be able to use the returned class directly:

```
+ (Parser *)parser_AccessList
{
    switch ([self brand]) {
        case Brand1:
            return [Parse_AccessList_1 alloc];
            break;

        case Brand2:
            return [Parse_AccessList_2 alloc];
            break;

        case Brand3:
            return [Parse_AccessList_3 alloc];
            break;

        default:
            return nil;
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing something really simple here.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a class name, you can use:  Class theClass = NSClassFromString(classNameStr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the class object. The caller may then instanciate on object of that very class or call class methods to it (by sending class method selectors).

```
return [Parse_AccessList_1 class];
```

Let's assume this is within the caller somewhere:

```
Class clazz = yourObject parser_AccessList];
[clazz performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```

As `clazz` is an object of type `Class` the related class method `someMethod` shoulc be called.

However, I am sure there are better ways of reaching your goal. Try using a delegation pattern and/or dependency inversion.

Comment: Thank you. This does in fact work. I did try adding a protocol, however the caller doesn't seem to see the method definitions for some reason.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the Xcode autocompletion working with this method?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of keeping the autocompletion working. 
XCode cannot determine which class you are dealing with. You may even get some warnings related to ARC when you convert methods dynamically from strings.

Answer (score 1):

This method (message):

```
parser_AccessList
```

Is returning:

```
(Parser *)
```

That means that it will always return that allocated class type, so if you want to return "any" class you should define your method like this:

```
+ (id)parser_AccessList
```

The problem with this is that you don't know which class you should expect, so probably you are going to validate it after initialized.

Also, are you sure you don't need to initialize those parsers?

```
...
return [[Parse_AccessList_1 alloc] init];
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It's starting to make a bit more sense now. The reason I assume I don't need to initialise is currently when using the parser I simply use `[Parse_AccessList_1 method]` as methods are class methods. Returning as `id` the caller doesn't recognise any of the methods :(

Comment: which methods do you have?, you could define a method named `Parse (or whatever)` in `Parser` and implement it on every subclass, so you can know for sure that method is defined, in that case you should define your method as `+ (Parser *)parser_AccessList`

Comment: You can also add a protocol and define the class method in it, then return `id<MyProtocol>` in the factory method

Comment: That's exactly what i've just tried. I gave the Parse base class a protocol and added the method name. Return id<Parse_Protocol> and the code compiles fine, however it crashes with `unrecognised selector` on the method I called. The crash is showing the correct Parse class which is a start I guess

Comment: I have managed to get it working with Hermann's answer. By changing the return type to `Class`

Answer (score 0):

In class methods "self" is the class itself. When allocating an instance ([Parse_AccessList_1 alloc]) you have to initialize!

EDIT:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

...

```
Class cl = NSClassFromString(@"TestClass");
return [[cl alloc] init];
```